# Cloudformation for quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to build cloudformation template for Quicksight but there are no good examples to refer.Anyone with experience in creating cloudformation for Quicksight can you please let me know how can I start with CFT for quicksight

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_QuickSight.html) CloudFormation types reference for general guidance. You may also benefit from tools such as [Former2.com](https://former2.com) (free and open source), which helps generate CloudFormation from existing resources.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of Former2*

Answer (score 2):

Below is what I test so far that seems work.

1. Start with template to setup data source and data set. Make sure grant permission to QuickSight group that need access to this data set.
2. In QuickSiight UI use new data set to create and design Analysis. Once ready, get ARN for the analysis to be used in template.
3. In CF template , create QuickSight Template reference analysis ARN from above . Then create Dashboard with this new QuickSight template.
4. Also you can setup Dashboard permission to group that need access.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Abhishek from what I can tell Quicksight is broken with AWS Cloudformation bug is here: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/274

The documentation is either wrong when it says required and also there is a circular dependency between templates and analyses.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this CloudFormation YAML example helps https://ee-assets-prod-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/modules/5d114953b9c3484b92e6193fa1b1bac9/v1/DeployQSAssetsViaTrueCF.yml
This is coming from https://devops.learnquicksight.online/quicksight-via-cloudformation.html

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old, but I stumbled on it so thought I'll put out a new answer that addresses this. There are several Amazon QuickSight resources now in AWS CloudFormation that can be used to automate your QuickSight deployment. Read the full list in [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_QuickSight.html).

At the time of this answer, the list includes:

```
AWS::QuickSight::Analysis
AWS::QuickSight::Dashboard
AWS::QuickSight::DataSet
AWS::QuickSight::DataSource
AWS::QuickSight::Template
AWS::QuickSight::Theme
```

One important thing to mention is that you need an existing analysis or template to start the automation. So, that would have to be something shared to you, or something that you built out as a first pass and then converted to a template. Once you have that in place, you can automate the rest of the pieces.

This [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/automate-deployment-of-an-amazon-quicksight-analysis-connecting-to-an-amazon-redshift-data-warehouse-with-an-aws-cloudformation-template/) has the details of creating `DataSource`, `DataSet`, `Template` and `Analysis` resources.